# Async/Await in for loop NodeJS Not blocking the loop execuation

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I know that old school `for` loop works in the traditional way - that it waits for the `await` to finish getting results.
But in my use case, I need to read a file from local/s3 and process it line by line, and for each line I need to call an External API.
Generally I use `await` inside the loop because all are running inside a lambda and I don't want to use all memory for running it parallelly.
Here I am reading the file using a `stream.on()` method, and in order to use await inside that, I need to add async in read method, like so:

```
stream.on('data',async () =>{
         while(data=stream.read()!==null){
           console.log('line');
           const requests = getRequests(); // sync code,no pblms
           for(let i=0;i<requests.length;i++){
             const result = await apiCall(request[i);
             console.log('result from api')
             const finalResult = await anotherapiCall(result.data);
             }
        }
});
```

This is working but order in which the lines are processed is not guaranteed. I need all in a sync manner. Any help?

### Complete Code

```
async function processSOIFileLocal (options, params) {
console.log('Process SOI file');

const readStream = byline.createStream(fs.createReadStream(key));
readStream.setEncoding('utf8');
const pattern = /^UHL\s|^UTL\s/;
const regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
readStream.on('readable', () => {
    let line;
    while (null !== (line = readStream.read())) {
        if (!regExp.test(line.toString())) {
            totalRecordsCount++;
            dataObject = soiParser(line);
            const { id } = dataObject;
            const XMLRequests = createLoSTRequestXML(
                options,
                { mapping: event.mapping, row: dataObject }
            );
            console.log('Read line');
            console.log(id);
            try {
                for (let i = 0;i < XMLRequests.length;i++) {
                    totalRequestsCount++;
                    console.log('Sending request');
                    const response = await sendLoSTRequest(
                        options,
                        { data: XMLRequests[i],
                            url: LOST_URL }
                    );
                    console.log("got response");
                    const responseObj = await xml2js.
                        parseStringPromise(response.data);
                    if (Object.keys(responseObj).indexOf('errors') !== -1) {
               
                        fs.writeFileSync(`${ERR_DIR}/${generateKey()}-${id}.xml`, response.data);
                        failedRequestsCount++;
                    } else {
                        successRequestsCount++;
                        console.log('Response from the Lost Server');
                        console.log(response[i].data);
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }
})
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('file processed');
        console.log(`
        ************************************************
        Total Records Processed:${totalRecordsCount}
        Total Requests Sent: ${totalRequestsCount}
        Success Requests: ${successRequestsCount}
        Failed Requests: ${failedRequestsCount}
        ************************************************
        `);
    });
}

async function sendLoSTRequest (options, params) {
const { axios } = options;
const { url, data } = params;
if (url) {
    return  axios.post(url, data);
// eslint-disable-next-line no-else-return
} else {
    console.log('URL is not found');
    return null;
}
```

}

Code needs to flow like so:
read a line in a sync way
process the line and transform the line into an array of two members
for every member call API and do stuff
once line is complete, look for another line, all done in order

UPDATE: Got a workaround..but it fires stream.end() without waiting stream to finish read

```
async function processSOIFileLocal (options, params) {
console.log('Process SOI file');
const { ERR_DIR, fs, xml2js, LOST_URL, byline, event } = options;
const { key } = params;
const responseObject = {};
let totalRecordsCount = 0;
let totalRequestsCount = 0;
let failedRequestsCount = 0;
let successRequestsCount = 0;
let dataObject = {};
const queue = (() => {
    let q = Promise.resolve();
    return fn => (q = q.then(fn));
})();
const readStream = byline.createStream(fs.createReadStream(key));
readStream.setEncoding('utf8');
const pattern = /^UHL\s|^UTL\s/;
const regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
readStream.on('readable', () => {
    let line;
    while (null !== (line = readStream.read())) {
        if (!regExp.test(line.toString())) {
            totalRecordsCount++;
            dataObject = soiParser(line);
            const { id } = dataObject;
            const XMLRequests = createLoSTRequestXML(
                options,
                { mapping: event.mapping, row: dataObject }
            );
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
            queue(async () => {
                try {
                    for (let i = 0;i < XMLRequests.length;i++) {
                        console.log('Sending request');
                        console.log(id);
                        totalRequestsCount++;
                        const response = await sendLoSTRequest(
                            options,
                            { data: XMLRequests[i],
                                url: LOST_URL }
                        );
                        console.log('got response');
                        const responseObj = await xml2js.
                            parseStringPromise(response.data);
                        if (Object.keys(responseObj).indexOf('errors') !== -1) {
                            // console.log('Response have the error:');
                            // await handleError(options, { err: responseObj, id });
                            failedRequestsCount++;
                            fs.writeFileSync(`${ERR_DIR}/${generateKey()}-${id}.xml`, response.data);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Response from the Lost Server');
                            console.log(response[i].data);
                            successRequestsCount++;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('file processed');
        console.log(`
            ************************************************
            Total Records Processed:${totalRecordsCount}
            Total Requests Sent: ${totalRequestsCount}
            Success Requests: ${successRequestsCount}
            Failed Requests: ${failedRequestsCount}
            ************************************************
            `);
        Object.assign(responseObject, {
            failedRequestsCount,
            successRequestsCount,
            totalRecordsCount,
            totalRequestsCount
        });
    });
```

}

Thank You

Comment: do `apiCall` and `anotherapiCall` return a `Promise`?

Comment: Yes..it return promise

Comment: by the way, in your *actual* code, you only have ONE await ... and you don't await xml2js.parseStringPromise(response.data) - which seems odd - you also have a stray `*/` - which would cause an error - you also have no `.on('data'` in the complete code ... so ... the pseudo code doesn't match the complete code in any sense

Comment: `it return promise` ... both? do you *await* both of them (doesn't look like it)

Comment: i need to await response from first call abd that data is passe to second async function

Comment: yes, that code at the top will do that as long as those apiCall and anotherapiCall return promises ... the only issue of course is, if they take a long time, `.on('data'` could be called subsequently .... you'll need to implement some sort of queue

Comment: yeah.. as you know that, if i use async at the top of readstream.on() order cannot be guaranteed..that's the problem

Comment: I think the issue is that the stream call back is being called while its prior instances are still running. You might consider pausing the stream as the first action in your callback so that the stream does not emit any events until you resume it at the end of your callback's processing.

Comment: but while( reader.read()) do the same stuff..isn't? one thing is, if i remove the async from the top, remove the await calls it works as we expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone want a solution for synchronisely process the file, ie, linebyline read and execute some Async call, it's recommended to use inbuilt stream transform. There we can create a transform function and return a callback when finishes.
That's will help of any one face this issues.
Through2 is a small npm library that also can be used for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code at the top of your question could be rewritten like

```
const queue = (() => {
    let q = Promise.resolve();
    return (fn) => (q = q.then(fn));
})();
stream.on('data', async() => {
    while (data = stream.read() !== null) {
        console.log('line');
        const requests = getRequests(); // sync code,no pblms
        queue(async () => {
            for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
                const result = await apiCall(request[i]);
                console.log('result from api');
                const finalResult = await anotherapiCall(result.data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hopefully that will be useful for the complete code

Comment: Did you use it for the `stream.on('data',async () =>{` code? (not sure what that second lot of code has to do with the question) - when you say it didn't work, was there an error? or it simply didn't do what you want @Sreejithsreeji?

Comment: First code is a absolute psudo code nothing related to second one.second one is the completed code..

Comment: the two codes are so different perhaps you implemented my suggestion wrong with your real code @Sreejithsreeji - so, when you say it didn't work ... what happened?

Comment: it's worked..but .end() is called before this queue function finishes..how to avoid that

Comment: @Sreejithsreeji - put everything inside `.on('end', () => { **your code** })` inside a call to `queue` ... i.e. `.on('end', () => queue(() => { **your code** }) )`